# HTML5: Whenever I send a text area message to fill out the body of an email the name of the text area proceeds it. How do I fix this?

Tags: javascript, html, email, message

Basically whenever I send a text area message to fill out the body of an email, the name of that text area always proceeds it. So, for example, if I type in "Hello World" into text area and then press send, my email application opens and the body reads: "message=Hello World". How do I get rid of the "message=" part? Thank you very much and heres my current HTML5 code:

```
<section id="contact" class="four">
    <div class="container">

        <header>
            <h2>Contact</h2>
        </header>

        <p>Send me a message: </p>

        <form method="post" action="mailto:abc@abc.net" enctype="text/plain">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="12u$">
                    <textarea name="message" placeholder="Message"></textarea>
                </div>
                <div class="12u$">
                    <input type="submit" value="Send Message" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>             
    </div>
</section>
```

Comment: I don't think that there is an easy way to do that, without using a server side script/solution.

Comment: By not using a `mailto` form. You don't have any control over how the email is formatted otherwise.

Comment: @hobbs What would you recommend as an alternative to 'mailto'?

Answer (score 0):

It may not be exactly what you're after but if you change your form method to GET and change the name of textarea to 'body' it will work as you expect without the tags. 
Using the post method encodes the data and mail client's dont know how to had it without the tags.
You can read more about it here: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/279460

```
<section id="contact" class="four">
<div class="container">

    <header>
        <h2>Contact</h2>
    </header>

    <p>Send me a message: </p>

    <form method="GET" action="mailto:abc@abc.net" enctype="text/plain">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="12u$">
                <textarea name="body" placeholder="Message"></textarea>
            </div>
            <div class="12u$">
                <input type="submit" value="Send Message" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>             
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. Unfortunately, while it did get rid of the tags, there are now plus signs where there should be spaces. For example, now if I type "Hello World!" it comes out as "Hello+World!".